# Is there any tool that converts Objective C code to java for Android

Tags: java, iphone, android, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Objective-C to Java cross compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792062/objective-c-to-java-cross-compiler)

I have a working iPhone app and want to convert to Android app with minimal effort. Can anyone suggest ?

Comment: The programming language is the smallest of your worries. What about the UI layouts? API calls? Framework setup?

Comment: @EboMike: Just read "minimal effort" as "lazy". I don't think he really cares that much anyway.

Comment: There's a tool called "O2J" on the Mac App Store.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so.  You're best bet would have been to develop the application from scratch using a platform like [Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/) or [Phone Gap](http://www.phonegap.com/).

The commenter makes an excellent point: the platforms are fundamentally different.  A straight conversion of code won't work.  You also have to convert framework/api calls and restructure all of your UI.  Not only is the framework different, but the assumptions made by the platform are totally different as well.

Possibly the best way to reuse the most code (this isn't necessarily the easiest, keep in mind) would be to convert as much objective c code into C or C++ and make use of the Android NDK.  You won't be able to reuse any of the UI code, but you might be able to reuse a significant amount of your application logic depending on what your application does.

Comment: Thanks .. I don't know how good it is, but this is a product I plan to investigate at some point. 
 
http://www.anscamobile.com/

Comment: anyone get a chance to play with anscamobile ??

Comment: That should probably be a separate question.