# Converting an Objective C code into java code

Tags: java, objective-c

Is there any tool available to convert objective C code into java ?

Comment: There is the "hire a programmer" tool.  Seriously, the software you get from a typical cross-language translator is ugly and hard to maintain.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C to Java cross compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792062/objective-c-to-java-cross-compiler)

Comment: And according to that question AND a Google search, the answer is "no".

Comment: dunno, obj-c to java should be a trivial task for a person who knows both languages. Besides the native library support and pointer arithmetic there is nothing hard. Side note: the correct term is "porting" not "converting"

Comment: If you "translate" from one language to another, the correct term is converting or translating and not porting. Porting you do from one platform to another usually keeping the language (like from OS X to windows or linux)

Answer (score 5):

You can try this thing: [Objc2j](http://code.google.com/p/objc2j/)

Comment: AFAIK needs a Mac. Please confirm before you go ahead with Windows!

Comment: @RavindranathAkila It doesn't need a Mac, trust me.

Comment: Hmmm... Even tried in Mac and failed. I noticed it can't work with GCD related code.

Comment: Not working... it crashes easily or produces really bad code. O2J mentioned by @Cal seems to work better.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout out [apportable](http://www.apportable.com/). It's much better than trying to convert your source code to Java. Just leave it in Objective-C and use Apportable to run your code on other platforms.

Comment: It looks like it's dead :(

Answer (score 1):

You should try [O2J - Objective-C to Java source code translator](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/o2j-objective-c-to-java-automatic/id988532240?ls=1&mt=12) from the Mac App Store. It is a cheap and very effective way to generate native Java code from your Objective-C.

Comment: Thank you. It's far from perfect but gives you some code to start with. And it's the only working solution I've found so far.