# Gen Android app from Objective-C source code

Tags: android, objective-c

I'm developing an application in Objective-C. Is there a way to translate Objective-C based source code into an Android based source code without developing an Android app from scratch?

Comment: wouldn't that be nice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting an Objective C code into java code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482511/converting-an-objective-c-code-into-java-code)

Comment: The difficulty of converting Objective-C code into Android code is not just about the programming language conversion. There are two very different frameworks used as foundation for both platforms. But there are some projects that may help you share code partially but the shared code will possibly be the business logic part, not UI.

Comment: See http://www.apportable.com/ to build Objective C apps for Android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so, usually people look at things like monotouch and phone gap before development time.

jumping languages and platforms like that would be very very tricky.

This might help: https://code.google.com/p/objc2j/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You are indeed right about using cross-platform tools. My point is that I'm not sure my concept will work. So I'm experimenting it on an OS I master before trying to deploy it on several differents OS.

Answer (score 2):

Converting the code perfectly would be near impossible, but [this](https://code.google.com/p/objc2j/) does exist.

Keep in mind though that Android is very different from iOS, and porting an app like this will almost definitely not work out for you.

It would be much more worthwhile to write it from scratch on Android if you are serious about having a market on the platform.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll have a look on it.